integrated webcam (ACER SP514-51N) not working
I don't know if this is the right place (in case it's not, please redirect me to more appropriate site), but trying - the integrated camera on ACER SP514-51N is not working in GNU/Linux. On the same machine, when MS Windows is booted, works just fine.
According to ACER forum (link below), it is a CHICONY model "CJFKF28"
How to make the camera working?
Here is some debug info from GNU/Linux (latest stable POP_OS, currently on kernel 6.9.3-76060903-generic #202405300957~1726766035~22.04~4092a0e):
spin5 :: ~ » sudo lsmod | grep -iE "video|cam"
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         36864  0
videobuf2_common       81920  3 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_memops
videodev              356352  4 v4l2_async,v4l2_fwnode,videobuf2_v4l2,ov2740
mc                     81920  5 v4l2_async,videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,videobuf2_common,ov2740
video                  73728  3 acer_wmi,xe,i915
wmi                    28672  3 video,acer_wmi,wmi_bmof
spin5 :: ~ » sudo dmesg | grep -iE "video|cam"
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.100395] PCI: ECAM [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (base 0xc0000000) for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff]
[    0.100395] PCI: not using ECAM ([mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] not reserved)
[    0.224013] PCI: ECAM [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (base 0xc0000000) for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff]
[    0.226296] PCI: ECAM [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] reserved as ACPI motherboard resource
[    0.495588] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    7.005562] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    7.006168] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input18
[    8.942344] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[ 1755.195885] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[ 2471.824739] usbcore: deregistering interface driver uvcvideo
spin5 :: ~ » sudo lsusb                       
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c7f Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
spin5 :: ~ »

Here is some selected info from MS windows device list:
Intel(R) ADL AVStream Camera
DISPLAY\INT3480\4&2DED5861&0&UID144512
VIDEO\VEN_8086&DEV_46A6&SUBSYS_16131025&REV_0C&INT3480
VIDEO\VEN_8086&DEV_46A6&SUBSYS_16131025&INT3480
VIDEO\VEN_8086&DEV_46A6&INT3480
VIDEO\INT3480
000000E0
CM_DEVCAP_SILENTINSTALL
CM_DEVCAP_RAWDEVICEOK
CM_DEVCAP_SURPRISEREMOVALOK
oem80.inf
ks.inf
KSCAPTUR.inf
machine.inf
ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PC00)#ACPI(GFX0)#ACPI(IPUA)
oem81.inf:VIDEO\INT3480,iacamera64.NT,12/30/2021,63.22000.3.6744
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_46A6&SUBSYS_16131025&REV_0C\3&11583659&0&10
\Device\000000a4
\_SB.PC00.GFX0.IPUA
Intel(R) ADL AVStream Camera
ISP Camera Device
ACER FHD User Facing

Thanks a lot!
Related:
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/1302958#Comment_1302958
Duplicate here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1858660/how-to-enable-the-internal-camera-on-acer-spin-sp514-51n-laptop-in-gnu-linux
(I am figuring out which forum is more suitable for this question and solution)

There is something weird : VEN_8086 means "Intel"

Thanks for pointing out, but indeed, this is the correct device - I will let them know on the ACER forum.

AVStream Camera will not work (yet? probably never?). They are "windows only" camera, with mixed driver from Microsoft and the vendor. A few years ago, lots of small printers had the same problem.
